# React Apollo client v3. Offset-based pagination. Fails to fetch data from cache

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I've implemented offset-based pagination as described in Apollo client documentation. When I switch from page 1 to page 2, from page 2 to page 3 etc the gql-query to GraphQL server takes place. But when I go back from page 3 to page 2 and from page 2 to page 1 gql-query is also triggered. Which means cached data is not fetched (data is stored in cache in a single list as expected). Any ideas why this might happen? Has anyone implemented pagination exactly as it is described in the documentation?

```
const {loading:loadingHistory, data:historyData, fetchMore} = useQuery(getHistoryOffsetPaged, {
  variables: {
    offset: 0,
    limit: store.selectedNumberOfElements
  }
})
```

```
<PageButtons
  totalPages={store.historyTotalPages}
  currentPage={store.historyCurrentPage}
  changePage={page => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        offset: (page - 1) * store.selectedNumberOfElements,
        limit: store.selectedNumberOfElements
      }
    })
    store.setHistoryCurrentPage(page)
   }}
/>
```

```
export const getHistoryOffsetPaged = gql`
    query(
        $offset: Int,
        $limit: Int) {
        getHistoryOffsetPaged(
            offset: $offset,
            limit: $limit) {
                id
                dateTime
                curFrom
                curTo
                exRate
                sumBeforeConversion
                sumAfterConversion
                averageExRate
            }
        }
`
```

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        getHistoryOffsetPaged: {
          keyArgs: false,
          merge(existing, incoming, {
            args: {
              offset = 0
            }
          }) {
            const merged = existing ? existing.slice(0) : [];
            for (let i = 0; i < incoming.length; ++i) {
              merged[offset + i] = incoming[i];
            }
            return merged;
          },
          read(existing, { args }) {
            return existing && existing.slice(
                args?.offset,
                args?.offset + args?.limit);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have the same issue and it seems the cache is replaced even though the offset value is changing it is always set to 0 and replaces the data.